# getOwnPropertyNames ignores __proto__ on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, language-lawyer, ecmascript-6, ecma262

`__proto__` is a property of `Object.prototype`:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('__proto__'); // true
```

However, getOwnPropertyNames ignores it on Firefox:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype).indexOf('__proto__'); // -1
```

It works on Chromium 43 and IE 11, tough.

AFAIK, according to ECMAScript 5 spec, getOwnPropertyNames should list it:

> [**15.2.3.4 - Object.getOwnPropertyNames ( O )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.4)
>
> When the **getOwnPropertyNames** function is called, the following
>   steps are taken:
>
> 1. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*O*) is not Object throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 2. Let *array* be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Array ()` where `Array` is the standard built-in
>      constructor with that name.
> 3. Let *n* be 0.
> 4. For each named own property *P* of *O*
>
>    1. Let *name* be the String value that is the name of *P*.
>    2. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *array* with arguments [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*n*), the PropertyDescriptor {[[Value]]:
>         *name*, [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **true**, [[Configurable]]: **true**}, and **false**.
>    3. Increment *n* by 1.
> 5. Return *array*.

`__proto__` is a named own property of `Object.prototype` (otherwise, [hasOwnProperty](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5) would return false because [[[GetOwnProperty]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5) would return undefined). Therefore, it should be listed by getOwnPropertyNames, shouldn't it?

Should that be different in ECMAScript 6? The ES6 draft changes a few things indeed:

> [**19.1.2.7 - Object.getOwnPropertyNames ( O )**](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.getownpropertynames)
>
> When the **getOwnPropertyNames** function is called, the following
>   steps are taken:
>
> 1. Return [GetOwnPropertyKeys](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-getownpropertykeys)(*O*, String).
>
> [**19.1.2.8.1 - Runtime Semantics: GetOwnPropertyKeys ( O, Type
>   )**](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-getownpropertykeys)
>
> The abstract operation GetOwnPropertyKeys is called with arguments *O*
>   and *Type* where *O* is an Object and *Type* is one of the ECMAScript
>   specification types String or Symbol. The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *obj* be [ToObject](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-toobject)(*O*).
> 2. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*obj*).
> 3. Let *keys* be *obj*.[OwnPropertyKeys].
> 4. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*keys*).
> 5. Let *nameList* be a new empty [List](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
> 6. Repeat for each element *nextKey* of *keys* in [List](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) order,
>
>    1. If [Type](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*nextKey*) is *Type*, then
>
>       1. Append *nextKey* as the last element of *nameList*.
> 7. Return [CreateArrayFromList](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-createarrayfromlist)(*nameList*).
>
> [**9.1.12 - [[OwnPropertyKeys]] ( )**](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type)
>
> When the [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method of *O* is called the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *keys* be a new empty [List](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
> 2. For each own [property key](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-type) *P* of *O* that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order
>
>    1. Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 3. For each own [property key](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-type) *P* of *O* that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order
>
>    1. Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 4. For each own [property key](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-type) *P* of *O* that is a Symbol, in property creation order
>
>    1. Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 5. Return *keys*.

[[OwnPropertyKeys]] should return a list which contains `"__proto__"`, and GetOwnPropertyKeys should return an array with `"__proto__"`, because its type should be String.

And even in case it was Symbol instead of String (which doesn't make much sense), [getOwnPropertySymbols](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols) should include `__proto__`, but it returns an empty array.

Therefore, is it a bug, or what intricacy of the spec applies here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be a bug. From [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=837630) (where similar oddities are observed):

> We filter __proto__ out of properties on objects without a
>   [[Prototype]], because we don't want to expose it to the web.  Or at
>   least that was the intent at the time, especially since no other
>   browser exposed the property on Object.prototype that way, and there
>   was a chance at killing __proto__.  I still have some hope that
>   __proto__ can be killed, myself; others disagree.

They will need to fix this for ES6.